# How can I use multiple containers with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I couldn't find anything online how can one use multiple docker containers with visual studio code. There's dev containers feature [available](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) for a long time already, but what if I need to launch redis and rabbitmq and some mysql or aerospike together with my application? I'm using docker-compose for dependencies currently.

I'm asking here because on their Github they recommend to ask on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Would expect to be a common requirement. That's what containers made for basically... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯